# Getting IOError trying to open file through Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, ioerror

I'm writing an app that opens a csv file and lays out the data with Kivy.
The csv file is stored in the same folder as main.py.

```
class BeerCellar(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BeerCellar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.beer_list = []
        with open(os.path.join('beer_archive.csv'), 'rb', 1) as beer_csv:
            beer_reader = csv.DictReader(beer_csv)
            for beer in beer_reader:
                beer_list.append(beer)
```

I'm able to open the csv file using IDLE, but when I right click main.py and select 'send to: Kivy 1.7.0' as Kivy is loading it up I get the following error:

```
    File "C:\Users\Knute\Python\projects\Kivy_Stuff\Cellar\main.py", line 34, in
__init__
    with open(os.path.join('beer_archive.csv'), 'rb', 1) as beer_csv:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'beer_archive.csv'
```

The file permissions are set to read/write for all.
Using Windows 7, Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `beer_archive.csv` does *not* exist in your present working directory, which is most likely the `C:\Users\Knute\Python\projects\Kivy_Stuff\Cellar` folder.

Without a full path, Python looks in the current working directory, and what that is depends on the way your program was started and if any calls to `os.chdir()` were made to change the current working directory.

Use a full path to your archive file:

```
with open(os.path.join(folder_path, 'beer_archive.csv'), 'rb', 1) as beer_csv:
```

where `folder_path` is set to the full path of the folder where `beer_archive.csv` is located.

Note that you can save yourself a loop if all you do is append the rows from your CSV to `self.beer_list`; the following will do that in one command:

```
class BeerCellar(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BeerCellar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with open(os.path.join(folder_path, 'beer_archive.csv'), 'rb', 1) as beer_csv:
            self.beer_list = list(csv.DictReader(beer_csv))
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn, that seems to have done the trick!  Double thanks for the loop saving tip.